# PHP socket_bind error (only one usage of socket address)

Tags: php, sockets

Below is a PHP script that I have created to listen for incoming  messages (XML strings).

That PHP script is hosted on my local home server on port 13330 so that's where I would listen for incoming requests, right? So I create the socket and bind it to the address the file is located on.

I receive this error: Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [0]: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

I would appreciate it if anyone could let me know why I might be seeing that.

Thanks

```
createSocketServer();

function createSocketServer() {

    // Set time limit to indefinite execution
    set_time_limit (0);

    // Set the ip and port we will listen on
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 13330;

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    echo '<p>Socket created</p>';

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
    echo '<p>Socket binded</p>';

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);
    echo '<p>Socket listening</p>';

    /* Accept incoming requests and handle them as child processes */
    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    // Read the input from the client &#8211; 1024 bytes
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);

    // Strip all white spaces from input
    $output = ereg_replace("[ \t\n\r]","",$input).chr(0);
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Most likely something is already using that port - what does netstat show you?

Comment: @symcbean Can I bind the socket port to the same port I'm hosting the WAMP server on or does it have to be different?

Comment: It has to be different: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Comment: @symcbean Ah, I see what you did there :P. I will tell you how I get on with a different port in a moment, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use this code before binding:

```
if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    exit;
}
```

for reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php

You can also check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php for details